# Upload Data to druid Incrementally

Tags: druid

I need to upload data to an existing model. This has to be done on daily basis. I guess some changes needs to be done in the index file and i am not able to figure out. I tried pushing the data with the same model name but the parent data was removed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the ingestion json file :

```
{
  "type" : "index",
  "spec" : {
    "dataSchema" : {
      "dataSource" : "mksales",
      "parser" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "parseSpec" : {
          "format" : "json",
          "dimensionsSpec" : {
            "dimensions" : ["Address",
"City",
"Contract Name",
"Contract Sub Type",
"Contract Type",
"Customer Name",
"Domain",
"Nation",
"Contract Start End Date",
"Zip",
"Sales Rep Name"
]
          },
          "timestampSpec" : {
            "format" : "auto",
            "column" : "time"
          }
        }
      },
      "metricsSpec" : [
{ "type" : "count", "name" : "count", "type" : "count" },
{"name" : "Price","type" : "doubleSum","fieldName" : "Price"},
{"name" : "Sales","type" : "doubleSum","fieldName" : "Sales"},
{"name" : "Units","type" : "longSum","fieldName" : "Units"}],
      "granularitySpec" : {
        "type" : "uniform",
        "segmentGranularity" : "day",
        "queryGranularity" : "none",
        "intervals" : ["2000-12-01T00:00:00Z/2030-06-30T00:00:00Z"],
        "rollup" : true
      }
    },
    "ioConfig" : {
      "type" : "index",
      "firehose" : {
        "type" : "local",
        "baseDir" : "mksales/",
        "filter" : "mksales.json"
      },
      "appendToExisting" : false
    },
    "tuningConfig" : {
      "type" : "index",
      "targetPartitionSize" : 10000000,
      "maxRowsInMemory" : 40000,
      "forceExtendableShardSpecs" : true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share more details, eg. ingestion task json?

Comment: There is a property - appendToExisting. Shall i make it True ??

Comment: are you sure about the interval ? There is huge period covered in it ?"intervals" : ["2000-12-01T00:00:00Z/2030-06-30T00:00:00Z"],  Is all your ingestion data in single file "mksales.json" ?

Comment: I have taken dummy values for the interval. I hope this does not affect the ingestion task. 
No, mksales.json is the incremental data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways using which you can append/update the data to an existing segment.

Reindexing and Delta Ingestion

You need to reindex your data every time new data comes in a particular segment.(In your case its day) For the reindexing you need to give all the files having data for that day.

For Delta Ingestion you need to use inputSpec `type="multi"`

You can refer the documentation link for more details - http://druid.io/docs/latest/ingestion/update-existing-data.html

Comment: I have just updated this property - "appendToExisting" : true. This also seems to work.

Comment: Yea, this creates an additional shard in the segment instead of overshadowing the old segment into new segment.

Comment: @mdeora How can we reindex with other files ? When I am passing the same data of a particular timestamp but one column as  different value from other file , it is getting overwrite and not getting roll-up with previous data.

Comment: @NoobCoder that is the intended behaviour. what behaviour you want to achieve?

Comment: @mdeora I just want to achieve that if I pass same data from other file , the previous data and new data must get roll-up. Not overwrite. Is this possible through native ingestion ? Also how can I provide multiple file with data of that day as you mentioned in your answer ?